# Why is this zero length and zero capacity slice not nil?

Tags: go

I'm going through a [Go tutorial](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/12) and I reached the lesson about nil slices where it says:

> A nil slice has a length and capacity of 0 and has no underlying array.

In order to show this they present this code which works

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s []int 
    fmt.Println(s, len(s), cap(s))
    if s == nil {
        fmt.Println("nil!")
    }
}
```

However, I tried to experiment and I replaced `var s []int` with `s := []int{}`. The console still prints `[] 0 0` as in the first case but no longer the `nil!` string. So why is the first one `nil` and the other one not?

Comment: The quoted line defines the characteristics of a `nil` slice, it does not define the characteristics of a slice that has 0 len and cap. The statement "the sky is blue" does no mean that everything that's blue is the sky. If you're interested in what `[]int{}` does, read up on [composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For  `s := []int{}`:
Because it is **initialized** to a new type (e.g. `struct`) with an underlying array, a length, and a capacity

> A slice, once **initialized**, is always associated with an underlying array that holds its elements.

For `var s []int` see [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types):

> The value of an uninitialized slice is nil.

[The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value):

> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is provided, the variable or value is given a **default value**. Each element of such a variable or value is set to the **zero value** for its type: false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for strings, and **nil** for pointers, functions, interfaces, **slices**, channels, and maps. This initialization is done recursively, so for instance each element of an array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value is specified.
>   These two simple declarations are equivalent:

```
var i int
var i int = 0
```

After

```
type T struct { i int; f float64; next *T }
t := new(T)
```

the following holds:

```
t.i == 0
t.f == 0.0
t.next == nil
```

The same would also be true after

```
var t T
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Outch! Thanks for the additional examples. I see where I got it all wrong. It does make sense now. I confused an uninitialized value with initialized to zero manually.